# Sphinx returning only exact matches

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I have a MySQL table, named `Locations` which contains locations from all over the world.

I've set up a SPHINX index on this table, writing the following things to my `sphinx.conf` file:

```
source src_geonames
{
    type                    = mysql

    sql_host                = localhost
    sql_user                = myuser_myuser
    sql_pass                = mypass_mypass
    sql_db                  = mydb_mydb
    sql_port                = port

    sql_query_pre           = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query_pre           = SET session wait_timeout=7200
    sql_query_pre           = SET session net_read_timeout=7200
    sql_query_pre           = SET session net_write_timeout=7200

    sql_query               = SELECT Locations.LocationId, Locations.LocationId AS geonameid_attr, Locations.Name AS name, Locations.AsciiName AS asciiname, Locations.AlternateNames AS alternatenames, Locations.countries_CountryId AS country FROM Locations WHERE Locations.FCode IN ('PPL', 'PPLA', 'PPLA2', 'PPLA3', 'PPLA4', 'PPLC', 'PPLCH', 'PPLF', 'PPLG', 'PPLH', 'PPLL', 'PPLQ', 'PPLR', 'PPLS', 'PPLW', 'PPLX', 'STLMT') OR Locations.FCode LIKE 'ADM%'

    sql_attr_uint           = geonameid_attr
    sql_field_string        = country
}


index geonames
{
    source                  = src_geonames
    path                    = /server06-disk4/sphinx_data/geonames
    charset_table           = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+C0..U+DF->U+E0..U+FF, U+E0..U+FF
    mlock                   = 1
}
```

**Explanation to the sql_query:** The column `Locations.Name` contains the exact name of the Location (ie: Paris, Rome, New York), the `Locations.AlternateNames` column, contains every alternate name for that location (ie: the names of the location in different languages, for example, for Bucharest, the alternatenames can contain Bukarest)

> Strangely, if I ommit the first `Locations.LocationId` from the `sql_query`, when I try to run indexer, it greets me with an error, that geonameid_attr can't be found, and it is being ignored. Why is this happening?

To test that everything works correctly, I've connected to the SphinxSQL from command line, and tried to run some queries, the following way:

`SELECT geonameid_attr FROM geonames WHERE match('@(name,alternatenames) "[query-string-here]"') LIMIT 0,10 option max_matches=200000`

What I was excepting from the above query, is that it would search both `alternatenames` column, and `name` column, and return everything that is exactly *[query-string-here]*, or has in it *[query-string-here]*.

But if I run the above query, searching for example: *Paris*, it returns some rows(correct rows, because I've checked it with MySQL), but If I search for *Pari*, it returns nothing at all.

As the string *Pari* is clearly a part of the string *Paris*, I would except that the sphinx search return at least the same results that it returns if I am searching for *Paris*.

> Where am I doing something wrong? Is there a problem in the way I am querying `Sphinx`, is there an error in my setup, and I am indexing my data wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first column is always used as the document id, so if remove it, then the alias is used as document id. Leaving it not usable for the attribute.

You don't need to duplicate the unique id as an attribute anyway. Just use 'id' directly it pretty much works anywhere can use attribe `select id from...`

As for matching. Sphinx is designed to match whole words.

If want part word matching, look at `min_prefix_len` or infix.

Recommend sticking with enable_star =1, if don't want to have to include stars see expand_keywords.

Comment: Yep, this was the problem, thank you, I tought that sphinx is automatically making MySQL `LIKE` searches, but I needed to set min_prefix_len, and use the `*`. Thanks